# TKinter. Refreshing variable taken from csv each 10 seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tkinter

Good evening. I have csv file that updates each 10 seconds. I want to display string value from it in GUI and keep it updated as label each 10 seconds (without button clicking).

I've tried several options using  `root.update_idletasks()`, `root.after` and `time.sleep(10)` however didn't get the required results.

My csv file is following:
[simple table with 2 rows and 1 column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T1B5.png)

My code is presented below.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
import time

#'while' loop is used to read from csv file each 10 seconds (however it seems that I use it unproperly)
while 1:
    
    #reading from csv file 
    df=pd.read_csv('outputs.csv') 

    #assigning string value to variable 'day'. This string value is udpated each 10 seconds inside the csv file 
    day=df.at[0, 'Date/Time']

    #creating function that updates label each 10 seconds
    def set_label():
        var = StringVar()
        var.set(day)

        label = tk.Label(frame, textvariable=var)
        label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        root.after(1000, set_label)
        root.update_idletasks()


    root  = tk.Tk()

    #creating frame 
    frame = tk.Frame(root)
    frame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

    #calling function
    set_label()

    root.mainloop()
    
    #to read from csv file again in 10 seconds
    time.sleep(10)
```

Please let me know how to display string value from csv in GUI and keep it updated as label each 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

`root.after` is probably the most straightforward way to go about this:

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd

# creating function that updates label each 10 seconds
def set_label(day):
    var = StringVar()
    var.set(day)

    label = Label(frame, textvariable=var)
    label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

def run():
    # reading from csv file 
    df=pd.read_csv('outputs.csv') 

    # assigning string value to variable 'day'. This string value is udpated each 10 seconds inside the csv file 
    day = df.at[0, 'Date/Time']

    # calling function
    set_label(day)

    root.after(10000, run)

root = Tk()

# creating frame 
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

root.after(1000, run)
root.mainloop()
```

This is just the conversion. If I remember correctly you wont actually need to create a new Label each time now so the code in `set_label()` could look more like

```
def set_label(day):
    var = StringVar()
    var.set(day)
```

Tkinter can be a little finicky, if it does not automatically update you can call a frame update using `frame.update()`, you will have to pass in the frame to the looping run function in order to do this.

Comment: The code you've provided does it's function - it reads data from csv every 10 seconds, it refreshes label with new value every 10 seconds. Thank you very much.

Comment: Regarding the second part of your answer - moving away label information from function. It could work however I was not able to do it properly - either got empty screen or variables issue. If you have chance, you could post it below as a separate answer, it would be great reference for future users. Thank you one more time!

Comment: Neither does this change the value of `day` every 10 second.